# AngularJS Drag & Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS. My requirement is to design a web app with Drag & Drop functionality.
My app needs the following feature:

- A slider from where I could select widget, drag them over from the slider and drop them over to a grid in screen
- I should be able to re-size the dropped widget in the grid
- should be able to re-position the widget on the grid in the screen.

Could anyone suggest any websites, plugins or tutorials that could help me get around with this. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-adds-event-listeners). There is an simple example for an `directive` that can add drag/drop functionality on elements.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sZ7tX56IEydbHi3D3LYo?p=preview) you can find a plunker for example.

Comment: Thanks Sven. I used Gridster plugin and it helped me.